# Angular UI Drop-down box inserting line break

Tags: angularjs

Folks,

In using the drop-down toggle of ui.bootstrap .. the component is adding a new line to my menubar instead of falling in line.

I have created a plunker for the same here. As you will see that between button3 and button 4 I have insert a dropdown toggle which breaks the menubar and goes to the next line.

http://plnkr.co/edit/gist:3662702

Any clue as to how I can avoid this ?

I am also placing the code below:

in html file:

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div class='btn btn-small' >Button1</div>
      <div class='btn btn-small' >Button2</div>
      <div class='btn btn-small' >Button3</div>

  <ul class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle">Drop-down menu</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li ng-repeat="c in collection">
        <a>{{c.name}}</a>
      </li>
      <li class="divider"></li>

    </ul>
  </ul>

  <div class='btn btn-small' >Button4</div>

  </body>
```

In js file:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.collection = [{"name":"Angular"},{"name":"Bootstrap"}];
});
```

Comment: Hi your plunker doesn't seem to be accessible anymore. Would it be possible to create a new one ?

Comment: yeah..seems like there was some issue with the plunker.. created a new one at http://plnkr.co/edit/l8U49h9gQlTSGWXtL1QQ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so your issue comes from the **ul** tag (the one with css class dropdown). In your case you should write something like :

```
<div class='btn btn-small' >Button3</div>
<span class="dropdown">
  <a class="dropdown-toggle">Drop-down menu</a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li ng-repeat="c in collection">
      <a>{{c.name}}</a>
    </li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
  </ul>
</span>
<div class='btn btn-small' >Button4</div>
```

Note how I replace the **ul** tag by a **span** one. By default the ul tag have a css property display set to block causing the line break. With the span tag the display is set to inline ensuring that the line will not break.

See the forked plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/zKeIJczttqBUzO9OchJy